# DNN : How can I edit the Source code of dnn News module in Existing DNN website?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

**I have already published dnn website. So Can I add my custom module in it?**

I have purchased **DNNGoxNews** the module with source code from dnn store. 
Now I want to modify some of the fields from some user control So How Can I achieve this.

I have already installed the module in my dnn website.But How can I modify the module.

Please point me the right direction.

Thank You

Comment: Modules are piece of codes, so you can modify it, if the module has no code-behind file (.cs file), that means you need to change the code and rebuild & upload new DLL, if so, simply change the desire codes and upload the file(s) and you ready to do  :)

Comment: Actually I am a new bee to DNN So, I have to make changes what ever  I want to source code and then  upload the extension not before that ?@MehdiDehghani

Comment: `DNN`'s modules are `UserControl`, if you are familiar with `User Control _.ascx_` files, so you are in luck, if not, you need to read about that concept first, then you can add/edit any module for DNN

Comment: Thnks for your advice :) @MehdiDehghani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to install this module in a development environment, which typically means a local copy of DNN

1. [Follow this tutorial for how to setup your development environment.](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1)
2. Once that environment is setup, go to the HOST/EXTENSIONS page
3. Install the SOURCE package of the module you purchased
4. Open up the Project file, or Solution, in Visual Studio 2015
5. Make your changes, compile the module/changes
6. Repackage the module for deployment, if the source code doesn't do it for you automatically you can [follow this tutorial](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/7).